# How to get query Params from URL along with generics and not as String for GET request in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, httprequest

I wanted to read the parameters with the same data type and not as string from my GET request. I am actually getting the entire Request params as String. Need to know if there is way to read the params with their specified data types

Comment: Just use the type you want, spring will do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Please refer below examples of GET and POST both which suits your problem.

**Suppose your Json is:**

{
"name" : "john"
"age" : 30
}

**Your mapping class is**

```
    public class user {

    private String name;
    private Long age;

    //getter & setter

}
```

Your controller class will be :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

@PostMapping("/add")
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
      System.print.out(user.getName());
}

// URL will be http://localhost:8080/user?userId=
@GetMapping
public void getUser(@RequestParam Long userId) {

}
// URL will be http://localhost:8080/user/1
// likewise you can specify multiple path variable in URL separated by "/"
@GetMapping
public void getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

}
```

Comment: Actually here my problem - I don't know what datatype my request param contains. So I am clueless about what datatype I will receive in my request.